# Unable to upload file to google drive using jmeter as getting below response

Tags: jmeter

The requested URL `/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart` was not found on this server.  That’s all we know.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your protocol, host and port, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads?hl=sr-CS#multipart) the correct URL should be something like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart
```

the relevant JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration:

[image]

if you have problems coming up with a proper HTTP Request sampler configuration be aware that you can just record the file upload request using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and your browser, just make sure to copy the file(s) you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)